# Same Node app works on Elastic Beanstalk when deployed manually with via CLI, fails when going through CodePipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, nuxt.js, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-codepipeline

I am trying to deploy a Nuxt app on `Elastic Beanstalk`, I have set up a `CodePipeline` pipeline which first grabs the source code from GitHub when a new commit on `main` is detected, then passes it on to a `CodeBuild` process, which builds the app using a `buildspec.yml` file. It's dead simple, but I'll include it anyway:

```yaml
version: 0.2

phases:
  build:
    commands:
      - yarn
      - yarn build
artifacts:
  files:
    - '**/*'
```

The `BuildArtifact` from the above is passed on to the Deploy step, which then basically puts the results of the build process inside `/var/app/current` on the `EC2` instance attached to the `Elastic Beanstalk` environment.

And here lies my problem: the app won't start:

```
Dec  5 09:08:14 ip-172-31-30-230 web: > nuxt start
Dec  5 09:08:14 ip-172-31-30-230 web: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:905
Dec  5 09:08:14 ip-172-31-30-230 web: throw err;
Dec  5 09:08:14 ip-172-31-30-230 web: ^
Dec  5 09:08:14 ip-172-31-30-230 web: Error: Cannot find module '../package.json'
```

However, ff I do a `yarn build` on my local machine from the *same source* and use `eb deploy` to push the build, **it works!**

I have downloaded the build artifact produced by `CodeBuild` and compared the contents of the `zip` files produced both by my locally run `eb deploy` and `CodeBuild` and... they're virtually identical.

I have also inspected the contents of `/var/app/current` on the instance via `ssh` both when there was a working deployment from `eb deploy` and when it was not functional after having been deployed via `CodeBuild`. The contents are the same, I could not find any difference.

Also, running `yarn start` via terminal worked when it was deployed from my local terminal and gave the same error that I saw in the `Elastic Beanstalk` logs when it was deployed from `CodeBuild`.

My hair is turning white, I can't figure out what's causing this mess.

Comment: Perhaps there is an environment difference between CodeBuild and EB. What architecture is your local machine? What EC2 instances are you deploying to? What runtime do you have in CodeBuild? Are you using packages with native dependencies?

Comment: @kgiannakakis My local machine is a Mac, I'm deploying to t4g.micro instances, there are no native deps and CB is running on aws/codebuild/standard:5.0

Comment: Since you are deploying on arm machines, perhaps it would be better to use aws/codebuild/amazonlinux2-aarch64-standard:2.0. Not sure, if it supports node 14 out of the box.

Comment: I have encountered the same problem. Moving from manually uploading the zipped files to using "eb deploy" I'm getting an error. Both files are identical. Definitely i'm missing something.